# Rails 3.2 - Assets that I do not wish to precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2 with asset pipeline.  It works fine, however there is one particular case where I want one particular third party assets no to be precompiled.

I moved the assets back into public/javascripts directory hoping that I can use the tool in the same way as before, however I get the following error at runtime:

```
tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js isn't precompiled
```

I am puzzled, because I thought the third party JavaScript tool would be excluded from asset pipeline just by putting it in the public directory.

In my view I have the following include:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce' %>
```

Any light on this subject would be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to move your vendor assets in `app/vendor/assets/javascripts` directory , but not in `public` . The `public`directory is used in production environment , after the assets are precompiled .

In case you rely on asset-pipeline , it is enough to include the `tiny-mce` in manifest file `application.js` like this :

```
/= require tiny_mce/tiny_mce
```

and avoid any `javascript_include_tag` in your views .

Comment: The problem is that the contents of `app/vendor/assets/javascripts` directory would also be precompiled.  The `public/assets` is used for recompiled assets, but I thought `public/javascripts` should contain the stuff that is not meant for precompiling.  I thought there's gotta be a way.

Comment: It seems like precompilation breaks 1 or 2 assets so I want to move the out of the asset pipeline precomilation.  It works all fine in development, but not so much after precompilation.

Comment: You mean if there is a way to separate assets on precompiled and not- precompiled ?

Comment: Yep that exactly what I want.  And placing stuff into `public/javascripts` seems to do it, except it complains at runtime.

Comment: I think you can try appending a new dir to asset-pipeline and not including it in the list of precompiled assets . It would be interesting . But if there is an error message , complaining "not precompiled" I doubt.